# targetSdkVersion 28 , FCM notification icon shows as blank black , but with targetSdkVersion 20 it will shows perfect app icon

Tags: android

I have use FCM for app related notification. Also receives notification successfully. But issue occurs with app icon. When targetSdkVersion 20 app icon shows perfectly fine. But targetSdkVersion 28 , App icon not display , it shows app icon as black/whilte round null icon. Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First** : Its not from Marshmallow, Notification icon started turning out WHITE from Lollipop itself.

Checkout http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html you will see that the white style is how notifications are meant to be displayed in Android Lollipop.

In Android Lollipop, Google also suggests you to use a color that will be displayed behind the (white) notification icon - https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0-changes.html

**Second** : Solution to this is setting LargeIcon to Notification Builder

```
Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
                .setContentText(data)
                .setContentTitle("Notification from Parse")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting in Android 8.0 (API level 26), all notifications must be assigned to a channel.

Please refer to
https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels

Answer (score 0):

Starting from targetSdkVersion 21, all notification icons must be black and white. You cannot use colored icons, Android will force a black and white filter in your notifications and they must look good on it.